# Is there a term that means that the numbers are well spread out?

Tags: word-request

For example: 1, 12, 34, 41 are well spread-out, but 1, 2, 3, 4 are not well spread-out. I guess spread-out can work, but I am looking for a single-word or a non-composite adjective to say this.

Comment: spread out compared to what?  1, 12, 34, and 41 are very close together if we are talking about numbers that reach into the thousands or more.  In mathematics, integers are adjacent if they are right next to each other, but 1 and 3 are not (however 11 and 13 are adjacent primes)

Comment: On the contrary, at least in terms of a pattern, I would say that 1,2,3,4 is much more evenly spread out than 1, 12, 34, and 41. (If you look at the lowest number and the highest number, and then the distribution of the numbers in between.)

Comment: 1,2,3,4 (each a difference of 1) are as evenly spaced as 1,11,21,31 (each a difference of 10) so I agree that 1,12,34, and 41 are (as Jason suggests) not as evenly spaced (or spread out) as 1,2,3,4

Comment: Maybe "dispersed" or "scattered". You might need to specify the space available for the numbers (such as integers 0 to 100) for any term to have meaning. But if you define terms in what you are writing, you could use anything you want.

Comment: Do you consider {1,2,3,41} to be spread out?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first has a larger range than the second.  My second choice is "notnexttoeachother", where the idea of running words together is borrowed from German.  Another more serious choice is disparate.

Comment: An upvote as a thank you for making me laugh! Oh, German...

Answer (score 0):

After puzzling over this for a good long time, I decided to adapt this question and then ask the experts over at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655973/what-mathematical-property-is-fulfilled-by-mathbbs-2-but-not-mathbbs-1). Looks like the best word for your situation, since you are dealing with [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) of numbers, is *[dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion)*. The set {1,2,3,4} is far less *dispersed* than the set {1,12,34,41}. One way to measure dispersion is range, which can be found by evaluating the highest number in the set minus the lowest number in the set. There are many other more complicated methods of measurement listed on the linked Wikipedia page for *dispersion* if you are mathematically minded.

Hope this helps!